# Reloading Flash with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a Flash file in my web page,the flash accepts a value as an argument and shows a graphics based on that. Now I want to know using JavaScript, can I reload the flash? So that when user enter a value and clicks on a button, the value will be passed to the flash file in same page and show the graphic (without loading the page again).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed the flash dynamically, or you could just put the flash object in a 1px by 1px container and show it when you're ready. To pass in the argument, you could expose javascript methods in the flash object, like in this [tutorial from adobe](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html).

Comment: swfobject is the best bet here. That framework can do all the dirty work of embedding/removing flash. It's simple to use as well.